# Get OS details - where Oracle EBS installed

Tags: oracle-ebs

I am raising an Oracle SR for some help regarding Oracle EBS R12. but I need to provide some information.
Operating System/Version - How can we get this information - is there any query or any way to get that info.

thanks and regards,
User

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Or on dba.stackexchange.com, the site dedicated to database admins.

Comment: Also, how the hell do you not know what operating system your database is on?

Comment: Hello Marcus... I respect your first two comments ... I will take that sincerely... But your third comment is not fair ... Well... I know its some Linux server not sure of the versions etc. Not knowing is not a Crime.  Hope you understand.

Comment: It's an enterprise business software package. Your company is paying *a lot of money* for that software. There is someone you can ask about the system it runs on, I'd presume.

Comment: Yes You are correct .. right now no one is available.. thought someone in Stackoverflow could help... any way... I will find some other resources.. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

$ uname -a

on the linux prompt.

in my case it is:

> Linux ebsdev.abc.com 3.8.13-98.4.1.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Wed Sep 23 18:46:01 P                                            DT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux